# Characterization of closed set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that $F\subset A$ is closed if and only if exists a closed set $W$ such that $F=W\cap A$.

Comment: If $A = [0,2)$ and $W = [1,3]$, then $F = W \cap A = [1,2)$ is not closed

Comment: Do you mean closed in the subspace $A$?

Comment: @AndreiKulunchakov $[1,2)$ is closed in the subspace topology on $[0,2)$.

Comment: Y es closed un A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset of $A$ is closed if and only if $F \setminus A$ is open, which means that $F \setminus A = A \cap W$ for some open set in the ambient space. Using principles of set theory,
$$
F \setminus A = A \cap W \implies F = A \cap W
$$
(Draw a venn diagram and convince yourself.)